# Sanitize roslyn memberdeclarationsyntax identifier

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is there any existing method or mechanisms in roslyn for sanitizing the identifier names of memberdeclarationsynxtax nodes when building synxtaxtrees?

for example names with spaces, dots, dashes or using reserved words like class, void, string

[Edit]
To clarify, the code is going to be generated so you do not know or have control over the input in advance, the goal is to sanitize the input. I am referring to the syntaxtree equivilent to Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() which you might use to sanitize input for creation of directories and file. I am asking if there is any such mechanism with roslyn.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that, it's not the compiler's job to tell you how you should name your members.

Comment: fair point, but the compiler will populate the diagnostic errors against a syntaxtree if I tried to name a class 'class' for example, so there must be some form of validation happening under the covers

Comment: You can call a class `class`: `class @class {}`

Comment: yes but the question is how do you identify those reserved words in order to prefix them with @

Comment: @Mac The simple solution is to prefix *everything* with `@`. `class @SomeValidName` is exactly the same as `class SomeValidName`.

Comment: Agreed, it would work, unfortunately for what I need, I cannot do that as it would cause havoc with legacy code. 
The compiler must know you cannot name members certain things otherwise how would it throw compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this answer. First of all, at the syntax level you will never have an `IdentifierNameSyntax` with the value of a reserved keyword. I know you're talking about method declarations, but the same idea applies to namespaces, (which have shallower syntax trees to look at).

Consider:

```
namespace class
{
}
```

The corresponding syntax tree (generated with the [Roslyn Syntax Visualizer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/70e184da-9b3a-402f-b210-d62a898e2887)):

[image]

Notice that in the above image `IdentifierName` has a lightning bolt next to it. This indicates that it's completely missing. The parser does not mistake `class` as an identifier. It knows that every time it sees the keyword `class` that it is the beginning of a `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.

Your syntax tree is absolutely destroyed and even Visual Studio does not realize you were trying to use an identifier with the value of "class". It indicates three errors:

- Identifier expected
- { expected
- } expected

The second part of this answer applies if you're generating identifiers and would like to detect if a string you've generated may be used as a valid identifier. I searched the codebase briefly and didn't notice any methods that would detect both invalid characters and keywords in identifiers. However, we can combine two methods to achieve what you want:

[`SyntaxFacts.IsValidIdentifier()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Parser/CharacterInfo.cs,a2cd6bb1895b6541) and [`IsCSharpKeyword()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#BoundTreeGenerator/BoundNodeClassWriter.cs,1dcced07beac9209) (which is unfortunately internal and must be copied into your program).

```
string myIdentifier = "test&";
bool validIdentifier = SyntaxFacts.IsValidIdentifier(myIdentifier); //false
string myOtherIdentifier = "class";
bool isKeyword = myOtherIdentifier.IsCSharpKeyword(); //true
```

Note that `IsCSharpKeyword()` does not check for [`Contextual Keywords`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/contextual-keywords) and they may appear within identifiers. However, naming your class `var` will likely introduce semantic errors so you might want to add these contextual keywords as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually talking about memberdeclarations which I think covers namespaces, classes, methods, properties, fields etc. 
This looks like it might do the job though

Answer (score 6):

While following up on the accepted answer, I found some additional methods on SyntaxFacts that could be of use here.

`GetKeywordKind(string)` returns a `SyntaxKind` representing the keyword, or `SyntaxKind.None` if the passed string isn't a C# keyword. `GetContextualKeywordKind(string)`does the same thing for contextual keywords. Which should make it easy to do something like:

```
string identifier = "double";
bool isAnyKeyword = SyntaxFacts.GetKeywordKind(identifier) != SyntaxKind.None
                 || SyntaxFacts.GetContextualKeywordKind(identifier) != SyntaxKind.None;
```